# Have a Custom Post Type index page display taxonomy items instead of posts

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, custom-post-type-archives, terms

I have a CPT registered that is called `lessons` with a custom taxonomy (category) that is called `courses`. I want the `/courses` page (archive-courses.php?) to display the individual courses (i.e. "online marketing", "paid advertising") and not the individual posts (lessons).

Would this mean I'd just customize the loop, or a complete custom WP_Query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like to list the individual courses, i.e. the taxonomy terms, you'd use neither [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) nor the WP standard [Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

Instead, make use of the [`get_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) function to retrieve the courses. It returns an array of term objects (if the taxonomy does exist and has terms matching the function arguments). Iterate over that and do something with it, such as displaying a list of links to the lessons:

```
$courses = get_terms( 'courses' );

if ( $courses ) {
    echo '<ul class="course-list">';

    foreach ( $courses as $course ) {

        echo '<li>' .
            '<a href="/courses/' . $course->slug . '" ' .
                'title="' . sprintf( 'View lessons of %s', $course->name ) . '">' .
                    $course->name .
            '</a>' .
        '</li>';

    }

    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its look like you calling `Custom Post (archive-courses.php)` not taxonomy. Try this `taxonomy-courses.php` also have a look [Custom_Taxonomies_display](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display.)

Comment: That would work for me if the `courses` page was a taxonomy archive page, it's not though. It is the archive of my custom post type.

Comment: yes! you are right. my mistake!

Comment: I appreciate the feedback though!